# Is there a way I can disable mods for specific players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

My friends and I want to do a Magic v Science server where each team can only use their given mods. Is there a way to prevent the magic team from using mods like Thermal Expansion, Industrial Craft 2 etc., and the science guys not having access to Ars Magica, Witchery etc?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately all **clients** must have the same mods and versions of the mods in order to connect to the **Host**. This means that every player will need the mods in order to even join your server and will have access to their content at all times.

Comment: Even if the clients must have them *installed*, could there be a way to disable them for a group players?